# Numpy create an index of values in an array and replace values by others

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have two sets of values `RGB` and `XYZ` in `np.arrays` that have the same length. The values in `RGB` and `XYZ` correspond to the same values in two different color spaces, **the order of their appearance** in the vectors is the same.

I have another array `RGB_picture` that contains values similar to the ones listed in `RGB`.

I want to find a way to replace the `RGB` values in `RGB_picture` by the corresponding `XYZ` values in a new array `XYZ_picture`.

example:

```
RGB = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]])

XYZ = np.array([[0.237,0.32,0.8642], [0.43234,0.34,1], [0.2432,.31,0.324], [0.3242,1.324,1.234], [1.32,0.4,0.23], [1.432,0.32423,1.342], [1.234,1.324,1.324324]])

#6 pixels image
RGB_image = np.array([[[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],
                       [0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1]]])

"""I want to return this"""

>print XYZ_image 

>[[0.43234,0.34,1],[0.43234,0.34,1],[0.43234,0.34,1]],

>[0.3242,1.324,1.234], [1.32,0.4,0.23], [1.432,0.32423,1.342]]
```

I tried to do it with numpy but couldn't find how, would you help a bit?

Here's what I have but it is no numpy solution, so it is very slow:

```
XYZ_image = np.zeros_like(RGB_image)

w, h = RGB_image.shape

for i in xrange(w):
    for j in xrange(h):
        pixel = RGB_image[i,j]

        for k in xrange(len(RGB)):

            rgb = RGB[k]

            if rgb == pixel:

                XYZ_image[i,j] = XYZ[k]
                break
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, and explain specifically where you are stuck?

Comment: Ok I added the variables, now I'm gonna add my trials

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use the RGB values as indexes. You can solve this with regular Python. Make a dict of

```
my_dict = {RGB_value_1: XYZ_Value_1, RGB_value_2: XYZ_Value_2, etc}
```

then for every value in RGB_picture

```
my_dict[RGB_picture_value]
```

EDIT: Using your code

```
my_dict = {RGB[i]: XYZ[i] for i in range(len(RGB))}
return [my_dict[x] for x in RGB_image]
```

Please note that for this to work, RGB, and RGB_picture values need to be immutable (like tuples)

Comment: immutable means it cannot be numpy arrays?

Comment: I would really prefer a numpy solution, the arrays are big

Comment: Right now, your RGB values are lists `RGB = np.array([[0,0,0], etc` Lists can be changed, they are mutable. If you change them to tuples, `RGB = np.array([(0,0,0), etc` then they are immutable, and you can use them for indexes in a dict.

Comment: yep, but the vector `RGB_image` is a numpy array